# How to check if current user is admin of a federated domain

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-apps

i have this method to check if the connected user is an admin of a google apps domain:

```
user = users.get_current_user()
if user and check_email(user):
    print 'user is a domain admin'
else:
    print 'user is not a domain admin'

def check_email(user):
    domain = urlparse(user.federated_identity()).hostname
    m = re.search('.*@' + domain, user.email())
    if m:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

after deploying on app engine server i got error 500, i have verified logs and got this track trace:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~apps/1.374581528892117369/handler.py", line 21, in get
    if user and check_email(user):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~apps/1.374581528892117369/utils/utils.py", line 18, in check_email
    domain = urlparse(user.federated_identity()).hostname
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/urlparse.py", line 142, in urlparse
    tuple = urlsplit(url, scheme, allow_fragments)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/urlparse.py", line 181, in urlsplit
    i = url.find(':')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

I have follow [this structures](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/marketplace/tutorial_python_gae) and didn't find the problem!
any idea of the root cause ?

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing this error because you're trying to call urlparse() with None.
Something like below should fix your problem.

```
def check_email(user):
    if user.federated_identity() is not None:
      domain = urlparse(user.federated_identity()).hostname
      m = re.search('.*@' + domain, user.email())
      if m:
          return True
      else:
          return False
```

Comment: yes but i think this is just a workaround to not got the error anymore, i have authenticated with admin account (admin@example.com) but got a None for `federated_identity()` i am looking for checking if the user is admin for a domain or not !

Comment: Can you check the response from federated_provider() or nickname()?

Comment: the `user.federated_provider()` is also `None` and `user.nickname()` return an error in this line:
`m = re.search('.*@' + domain, user.email())
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects`

Comment: I think that you're not actually logged in with federated identity.